# localizing master page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, master-pages

i am trying to localize my master page according to the selected linkbutton from the master page using  session.

Global.asax

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //set english as default startup language
    Session[Udev.MasterPageWithLocalization.Classes.Global.SESSION_KEY_CULTURE] = Udev.MasterPageWithLocalization.Classes.Culture.EN;
}
```

master page with link buttons: HomeMaster.master

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSetGerman" runat="server" Text="Nepali" CommandArgument="ne-NP" OnClick="RequestLanguageChange_Click"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSetEnglish" runat="server" Text="English" CommandArgument="en-GB" OnClick="RequestLanguageChange_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

HomeMaster.master.cs

```
public partial class Includes_MasterPage_HomeMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   }

   protected void RequestLanguageChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    LinkButton senderLink = sender as LinkButton;

    //store requested language as new culture in the session
    Session["MyCulture"] = senderLink.CommandArgument;

    //reload last requested page with new culture
    Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
   }
}
```

BasePage.cs

```
namespace Udev.MasterPageWithLocalization.Classes
{
/// <summary>
/// Custom base page used for all web forms.
/// </summary>
public class BasePage : Page
{
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        //retrieve culture information from session
        string culture = Convert.ToString(Session[Global.SESSION_KEY_CULTURE]);

        //check whether a culture is stored in the session
        if (culture.Length > 0) Culture = culture;

        //set culture to current thread
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);

        //call base class
        base.InitializeCulture();
       }
    }
}
```

Culture.cs

```
namespace Udev.MasterPageWithLocalization.Classes
{
/// <summary>
/// This class provides ISO definitions for all cultures that are supported by this application.
/// </summary>
   public struct Culture
   {
    //Nepali - Nepal definition
    public const string NL = "ne-NP";
    //English - Great Britain definition
    public const string EN = "en-GB";
   }
}
```

Global.cs

```
namespace Udev.MasterPageWithLocalization.Classes
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Global
/// </summary>
   public struct Global
   {
       public const string SESSION_KEY_CULTURE = "culture";
   }
}
```

So far my master page does not initialize any language whereas other pages only load the default language set in the global session.

Comment: I think your session_start default initialization is creating problem.Every time it sets default language.